# Why doesn't my file search work?

Tags: vba, file-io

I'm doing a check to make sure that my code is able to see my file before I move to the next step of my program. This is my code, but it always displays as the path not existing. Did I do something wrong?

```
Sub NewNameiLoop()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim NewNamePath As String

    NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
    NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

    Do While i < 99                               'Counts with the file name up to -099
        i = i + 1
        If vbOK Then
            MsgBox (Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3))
            If Dir(NewNamePath) <> "" Then
                MsgBox "Path Exists."
            Else: MsgBox "Path does not exist."
            End If
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Other information:

This code is in the module NewNameLoop in the sub NewNameiLoop.

The form it goes to is called Renamer. The form calls NewNameiLoop when the user clicks "Apply" to rename some files. After they are renamed, they call this code to check for the file's existence.

The MsgBox displayed contains the full, correct path.

This is in Autodesk Inventor, not Excel! Thus far, the coding has been pretty much the same. No weird quirks or anything.

[image: Accessing C:\]

[image: Accessing anything within C:\]

JPEGs of what is happening. As explained below, I AM able to access C:\ and things within C:. The first parts of my program make a whole new folder and copy a different folder's contents in to it. After that it goes to the original folder and renames all the files. So does that mean it is indeed a coding problem? No one seems to know.

Comment: This code is in a module. The relevant form is called "Renamer". 

The code itself works, it's just not seeing my file for some reason. 


Hahaha! The vbOK thing will be completely gone as soon as I figure this step out. Once I know it can find my file the whole message box thing will be completely gone. It will be gone, I promise!

Comment: "Works" just meaning it runs.

Comment: It did not like that at all ("Forms!"). I had Option Explicit up there. I didn't include it because I thought it was required for all modules...Is it not? Sorry, I'm new to this and am still learning a lot every day. Maybe it's a problem with the file path itself...When you said "unless the control has the focus" what did you mean? And yes, me too! It's existence is quite the hassle.

Comment: What is your full path ?? -- make sure it is a valid string (drive, folder, file)  It just dawned on me that your code is in Excel and not Access -- leave your original syntax for referencing the controls.  Option Explicit is not required, but I wish it was --too often see problems because people don't define things properly.

Comment: It is in neither actually. It's in Autodesk Inventor :) 

 The full path....as an example, is: C:\Users\aweaver.GKNSMI\Documents\Project Folder\SillyVBA\Blah-001.ipt    Thank you for the explanation of Option Explicit!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, so I would just code a  test subroutine that uses the "Dir", then manipulate the variable "NewNamePath" to start with just "C:\Users\", then work your way up until you find where it breaks.

Comment: Well, that was a great recommendation. It broke right at C:\Users

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apparently you can't do a 'Dir' on that folder.  But you can use FileSystemObject. 
Add a Project reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
Then adapt the following approach:

```
Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
If oFSO.FileExists(NewNamePath) Then
    Debug.Print "Found it"
Else
    Debug.Print "Not Found"
End If
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: It still can't find the files. Adding that will make life easier though. There's a lot of stuff like that I haven't been able to do without MSR. Glad I got it added now.

Comment: UGH!! My BAD!!  Use oFSO.FILEEXISTS not FOLDEREXISTS otherwise, I guess this is your computer at work, and your Tech staff has them locked down pretty darn tight? If so, ask them if they can allow full access to some folder for you.

Comment: Well darn, I guess the latter is the case. That's going to put this whole project on hold. Many people need to be able to use this program. Gah. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: If 'many people', that means a server, which you may be able to access.  Explain to your tech support team and see if they can grant access.

Comment: What is strange though is that I am able to rename a group of files, as well as create and delete a new folder in the C:\ drive through my program in other modules and forms...

Answer (score 1):

The Dir will return nothing if:
1) The .ipt file does not exists or the file name is different from what you coded
2) No access to the folder

If you are not concern with the filename I suggest to leave the NewNamepath as Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" and do a file search in this path for the file you are looking for

Comment: I thought of that about ten minutes ago. I ran some tests. I can access the C:\ drive but none of the folders within it. I tried making my own folders (which automatically go to read only) with the same result. That's fun, right?

Comment: I thought of that about ten minutes ago. I ran some tests. I can access the C:

Comment: @meer2kat When you make your own folders, you do it within C:\ and also resulted in no access - is that what you mean?  So at the end you don't have access?

Comment: I can open it and add files and stuff to it, but it won't let me actually access the path through VBA.

Comment: Basically, my code can find the C:\ drive itself but nothing within it

Comment: @meer2ka Ok so you could access the folder manually but not with VBA?  Is your Autodeck runs with different network / local account?  Because it sounds like access issue to me now, instead of coding issue

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. You and @WayneG.Dunn both seem to have arrived at that conclusion. I'm going to guess there's no way around it. Shame, I've been working on the main project for three weeks straight. I'll just have to see if I can come up with a way to circumvent that issue.

Comment: @meer2ka It sounds like the program is for multi users?  It would be better if your IT staff could give you a share folder on a network that's accessible for all user and you use it as your path

Comment: What is strange though is that I am able to rename a group of files, as well as create and delete a new folder in the C:\ drive through my program in other modules and forms...

Comment: Check with the .ipt file as well as its path, see if there's specific security setting?

Comment: All good on that account. I'm able to access it and even open one from within my program already on a different step.

Comment: ok sounds like you have that solved yourself.  You could post an answer or edit your question if you wish, thanks

Comment: Um I would if I had an answer but I don't. Thanks for all your help!